# Unmanaged C++ DLL's with same name coexisting in same process

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Using Visual Studio c++ V10, I am trying to figure out how to build a DLL and resolve a DLL naming conflict.  Here are the details.

Company S ships a product called `M.EXE`.  Assume that `M.EXE` is installed in `\S\BIN\M.EXE`. Company S statically links to a DLL called `U.DLL`, which is installed in  `\S\BIN\U.DLL`.  `U.DLL` contains open source code, and is built with Visual C++ compiler options `/Zc:wchar_t-`, which doesn't recognize wchar as a native type.

Company C ships a DLL called `O.DLL`, and publishes the API's for this DLL, and ships an import library for `O.DLL`.  Assume that `O.DLL` is installed in `\C\BIN\O.DLL`.  `O.DLL` statically links to a DLL called `U.DLL`, which is installed in `\C\BIN\U.DLL`.  `U.DLL` is built on the same open source code, but is built with Visual C++ compiler options `/Zc:wchar_t`, which does recognize `wchar_t` as a native type.

Ideally Company C and Company S would agree to build `U.DLL`using the same Visual C++ options, but that is not possible.

`M.EXE` from Company S is extensible, in that I can build my own DLL in unmanaged C++, call it `NODE.DLL` that `M.EXE` will invoke if I set everything up correctly.  I would like to build `NODE.DLL` so that it statically links to `O.DLL` from Company C.  But the problem is that once `M.EXE` is running, it has loaded the `U.DLL` library from `\S\BIN`, and the symbols from `\S\BIN\U.DLL` are slightly different than the ones in `\C\BIN\U.DLL`, because of how `U.DLL` was built by each company.  So when `M.EXE` attempts to load `NODE.DLL`, it fails, because when `NODE.DLL` loads `O.DLL`, which needs `U.DLL`, the symbols needed from `\C\BIN\U.DLL` are not there, because Windows sees `U.DLL` as already being loaded.

A diagram of the situation is as follows:

```
M.EXE static link to -> \S\BIN\U.DLL
M.EXE dynamic link to -> NODE.DLL
NODE.DLL static link to  O.DLL
O.DLL static link to \C\BIN\U.DLL
```

Effectively, I need both `\S\BIN\U.DLL` and `\C\BIN\U.DLL` to co-exist in the same process space, and have `M.EXE` use its version of `U.DLL` and `O.DLL` use its version of `U.DLL`.

Note that I do not have the option to rebuild `M.EXE` or `O.DLL` to change how they each load `U.DLL`.  They come from third parties, so the static linking can't be changed.  I also don't have the option of using `LoadLibrary` on `O.DLL`, because it is a C++ library, provided with an import library.

I believe that manifests can be used so that when I build `NODE.DLL` that is statically linked to O.DLL, I set things up in the manifest of `NODE.DLL` so that `O.DLL` loads its own copy of `U.DLL` that is installed in `\C\BIN\U.DLL`.  I just cannot figure out how to do this. Ideally, I'd like to not modify the manifest of `O.DLL`, but if that is the only solution, I'll live with that.

Comment: DLL's, DLL's EVERYWHERE! ( Sorry, couldn't help myself ) Hi and welcome.

Comment: Essentially the problem is that `O.DLL` in its IAT specifies that it links against `U.DLL`, unqualified.

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple DLLs with the same **filename** in the same process by loading one or more of them with absolute paths. This does require the DLL to be dynamically loaded, but behavior is otherwise identical.

Instead of linking during the build process, you need to `std::string moduleName = appPath + "\s\bin\u.dll"; LoadModule(moduleName.c_str())`. Because this is unambiguous as to which DLL needs loaded, it allows you to load multiple ones with the "same" name.

Once you have the module loaded, you can assign each of the necessary functions to function pointers, then either wrap those or use the legal but little-used [syntax of calling functions pointers as normal functions](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#call) (`funcPtr(params)`).

If you are on a more recent version of Windows, you may be able to use DLL manifests to strengthen the versioning/naming around the module and cause the EXE to load a different DLL than it typically would. I'm not familiar with how exactly this would be done, although it is documented on MSDN (and probably here as well).

Comment: This is not an option, because I don't have the ability to rebuild M.EXE or O.DLL .  They come from different third parties.

Comment: If one of those modules is using a partial or absolute path or one is using dynamic loading, then you might be able to get by. Otherwise, manifests will be your only chance.

Comment: I believe that manifests are the only choice.  I'd like to know what to put in the manifest to make things work.   Both M.EXE and O.DLL are built using import libraries that then load U.DLL using the normal DLL loading rules.  Each company puts their own version of U.DLL in their own BIN directory.  When M.EXE is run, it picks up its copy of U.DLL.  When you write a standard EXE that uses O.DLL, it picks up its copy of U.DLL.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the source DLL programmatically at runtiome by using the /delayload linker option (Linker/Input/Delay Loaded DLLs in VS project properties) along with a custom hook. In one of your source files, you'll need to define and register a delayload hook function. In the hook function's dliNotePreLoadLibrary notification handler, simply call LoadLibrary with an explicit path to the desired DLL, then pass the DLL's HMODULE back to the delayload code. The delayload code will resolve the imported functions to the DLL that you give it regardless whether another DLL of the same name is already loaded into the process.

Off the top of my head, your hook will look something like this (where MyCustomLoadLibrary needs to be replaced with code that calls LoadLibrary with the complete path to the desired DLL in the conflicting case, or just the unqualified filename otherwise):

```
#include <delayimp.h>
FARPROC WINAPI MyDliNotifyHook( unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli )
{
  if( dliNotify == dliNotePreLoadLibrary )
    return (FARPROC)MyCustomLoadLibrary( pdli->szDll );
  return NULL;
}
extern "C" PfnDliHook __pfnDliNotifyHook2 = MyDliNotifyHook;
```

Comment: This only works if NODE.DLL is the one linking to the conflicting DLL. After re-reading your question, I see that you say it is one of the dependent DLLs that links to the conflicting DLL. In that case, you'll have to resolve the import address table of the dependent DLL programmatically. That's not difficult to do, but it's too complex to describe the steps here.

Comment: 'resolve the import address table of the dependent DLL programmatically': can you give a pointer, wehre I can read more?

Comment: There are two cases: the case where the loader can successfully resolve all imports (albeit to the wrong DLL); and the case where the loader cannot resolve the imports. If your case is the former, I can provide some pointers. If your case is the latter, you have to essentially reproduce the Windows loader code (resolving imports and applying fixups, then calling the entry point function). There is precious little documentation and I don't know of any public sources of information. It is not for the faint of heart, but it is possible: I have done it successfully.

Comment: "If your case is the former, I can provide some pointers". Yes, please Sir.

Comment: harper, I just realized that you are not the OP. Since this is off-topic for the OP, please start your own question.

Comment: @Owen-Wengerd - my case is the latter.  The loader cannot resolve all of the imports.  Some are the same, and some are different.  Ideally, because both M.EXE and O.DLL are built by different third parties and I want to get support from each of the third parties, I really want M.EXE to use the implementation of U.DLL that it supplies, and have O.DLL to use the implementation of U.DLL that it supplies.  As I said in the original post, I think it can be done with manifests.  I just can't figure manifests out.

Comment: @Irv I have very little experience using manifests because my work usually requires support for older versions of Windows. It could work, and in theory should work, but I'm afraid I can't offer any concrete help with manifests.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.  This will require restructuring your code to use function pointers everywhere though.  See:

[MSDN web page for LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not an option, because I don't have the ability to rebuild M.EXE or O.DLL . They come from different third parties.

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky that U.DLL is Open Source. You will need to build a version that supports *both* the `/Zc:wchar_t-` and `/Zc:wchar_t` functions. The first option merely defines `wchar_t-` as `unsigned short`. You'll get a ton of linker warnings for duplicate symbols, for each function that doesn't have a `wchar_t` argument, but otherwise you just end up with a fatter DLL.

Mind you, if there are any global or `static` variables using `wchar_t`, then you'll have two copies of those as well. But you'd have the same effect if you shoehorned two copies of `U.DLL` in one process.